# How to parse math.add(x,y) for x and y values?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a better way to look for parenthesis and split the values? I have the below code which works fine but wanted to find out better alternatives.
Thank you!

math.add(200, 400)

```
Dim exp As String = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("(") + 1, str.LastIndexOf(")") - str.IndexOf("(") - 1)

Dim range As String() = exp.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim start As Decimal
Dim finish As Decimal

If range.Length > 0 Then
    start = Decimal.Parse(range.First)
    finish = Decimal.Parse(range.Last)
End If
```

Comment: `Parse math.add`, that doesn't make sense, you mean parse a string? So I assume the string maybe looks like `(200,400)`?

Comment: Anyways, you *could* get rid of all that and use `regex`: `(\d+)(?:,)(\d+)` [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/t3DP3O/1) demo is there...

Comment: You could use `\((\d+),\s*(\d+)\)` in case there's a space between the numbers. Then, get the value of `Group(1)` and `Group(2)`.

Comment: @Jimi yes, didnt think of the space.

Comment: @Jimi we were both wrong, those regex wont pick up decimals, doubles etc... `\((\d+\.?\d+),\s*(\d+\.?\d+)\)` that works :) See the [online demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-vb-dot-net-online#&togetherjs=wl5oUtFdMf)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ   That's probably why nobody has answered this question, yet. The context is very thin. Plus, some cultures use a comma as decimal separator. Also, the OP never specified any detail on the composition of these (strings?).

Comment: @Jimi more than likely, I just caught it as you mentioned something about the space inbetween, then I noticed it wouldn't pick up anything with decimals...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  It could be something more generic, as `\(([0-9.,]*),\s*([0-9.,]*)\)`

Comment: @Jimi agreed, generic would be fine as long as the input is consistent...